# test page redirection with Capybara + RSpec

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have a step_definition

```
Then(/^I should be redirected to the (.+?) page/) do |target|
  expect(current_url).to eq(Urls[target])
end
```

and generally it works quite well. Sometimes when I'm using the poltergeist driver it goes faster than normal and the current_url is still the old page. That's when I get errors like this:

```
Then I should be redirected to the login page                                                # features/step_definitions/navigate-steps.rb:64

expected: "http://example.com/"
got: "http://example.com/reset-password"

(compared using ==)
(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/step_definitions/navigation.rb:50:in `/^I should be redirected to the (.+?) page$/'
features/password.feature:100:in `Then I should be redirected to the login page'
```

Is there a way to make the matcher wait a little for the url to update?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't use the `eq` matcher with `current_path` or `current_url`. Instead, use the [`have_current_path`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/SessionMatchers#has_current_path%3F-instance_method) matcher provided by Capybara 2.5+

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(Urls[target], url: true)
```

The `have_current_path` matcher uses Capybara's waiting/retrying behavior, so it will wait for the page to change. I added the `url: true` option to make it compare the full url. If `Urls[target]` resolves to just a path, you can remove the option.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be something that used the waiting behavior.